# Linear Gradient with Round corners

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I am creating a background image using linear gradients. How to to add round corners for each linear gradient.

**Please provide solution without any changes in html** (cant use more than one div)

```css
.myStyle {

  height:500px;
  width: 900px;
  
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(lightgrey , blue),
    linear-gradient(lightgrey , blue),
    linear-gradient(lightgrey , blue), 
    linear-gradient(lightgrey , blue);

  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  background-size:
    100px 40px, 
    500px 60px,
    250px 50px,
    250px 60px; 

  background-position:
    0 0,
    0 80px,
    0 160px,
    0 220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myStyle"></div>
```

Comment: Do you need it to be only blocks of solid colors, or do you need these to be gradient-colors?

Comment: gradient colors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest might actually be to use svg for this instead of css-gradients.

You'll load it as a [data-uri](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) in the background-image property.
To make the rounded corner, you can use the [`rx`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/rx) and [`ry`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/ry) attributes of the [`<rect>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect) element.
To make the gradients, you can use svg's [`<linearGradient>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/linearGradient) elements.

```css
.mystyle {
  height: 900px;
  width: 500px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg' width='500' height='900' viewBox='0 0 500 900'><defs><linearGradient id='blue-grad' gradientTransform='rotate(90)'><stop stop-color='lightgrey' offset='0%'/><stop stop-color='blue' offset='100%'/></linearGradient></defs><rect x='0' y='0' width='100' height='40' rx='15' fill='url(%23blue-grad)'/><rect x='0' y='80' width='500' height='60' rx='15' fill='url(%23blue-grad)'/><rect x='0' y='160' width='250' height='50' rx='15' fill='url(%23blue-grad)'/><rect x='0' y='220' width='250' height='60' rx='15' fill='url(%23blue-grad)'/></svg>");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/*
  SVG Image unminified:
  
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="900">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="blue-grad" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
      <stop stop-color="lightgrey" offset="0%"/>
      <stop stop-color="blue" offset="100%"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="40" rx="15" fill="url(#blue-grad)"/>
  <rect x="0" y="80" width="500" height="60" rx="15" fill="url(#blue-grad)"/>
  <rect x="0" y="160" width="250" height="50" rx="15" fill="url(#blue-grad)"/>
  <rect x="0" y="220" width="250" height="60" rx="15" fill="url(#blue-grad)"/>
</svg>
*/
```

```html
<div class="mystyle"></div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Not really sure what is your goal but if you want gradient with solid color to have radius you can build it using multiple linear-gradient and radial gradient.

Here is an example where I am using CSS variable to easily define the position, size and radius. This is one of your gradient. You need to repeat the code for all the gradient and adjust the different values.

```css
.box {
  --w:200px; /*Gradient width*/
  --h:100px; /*Gradient height*/
  --r:10px;  /*Gradient radius*/
  --x:50px;  /*Gradient position x*/
  --y:40px;  /*Gradient position y*/
  --c:grey;  /*Gradient color*/
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,var(--c) 98%,transparent 100%) var(--x)  var(--y) / calc(2*var(--r)) calc(2*var(--r)),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,var(--c) 98%,transparent 100%) calc(var(--x) + var(--w) - 2*var(--r)) var(--y) / calc(2*var(--r)) calc(2*var(--r)),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,var(--c) 98%,transparent 100%) var(--x) calc(var(--y) + var(--h) - 2*var(--r)) / calc(2*var(--r)) calc(2*var(--r)),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,var(--c) 98%,transparent 100%) calc(var(--x) + var(--w) - 2*var(--r)) calc(var(--y) + var(--h) - 2*var(--r)) / calc(2*var(--r)) calc(2*var(--r)),
    
    linear-gradient(var(--c),var(--c)) calc(var(--x) + var(--r)) var(--y) / calc(var(--w) - 2*var(--r)) var(--h),
    linear-gradient(var(--c),var(--c)) var(--x) calc(var(--y) + var(--r)) / var(--w)  calc(var(--h) - 2*var(--r));
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="--w:80px;--r:30px;--c:red;"></div>

<div class="box" style="--h:80px;--r:40px;--x:5px;--y:5px;--c:blue"></div>
```

Comment: @Kaiido you don't see the radial gradient? or you don't see any gradient?

Comment: @Kaiido we are probably dealing with a bug or a lack of support. I just tested with an Android Device and it seems fine.

Comment: @Kaiido the OP want to have a gradient with border radius so I built its gradient using multiple gradient and in his code he is using `60px` then `0` for the values which will produce solid colors (basically rectangles). Don't know what the OP want but for me it's like he want many rectangles with radius and I show him how to build one then he need to duplicate the code.

Comment: Ok now I'm on a computer I can see better sorry for the mess then. So even though technically "<css-gradients>" these are not "gradient-colors", just blocks of solid color, and your solution does work for this particular case, but not for "real gradients" as I missed you are saying in your answer. Now indeed OP is not very clear and this may very well fit their needs.

Comment: @Kaiido I also have some ideas to make it working with real gradient but it would be an effort wasted if it's not what the OP want Or I will probably add it later to make the answer more generic.

Comment: [Seems you'll have to make that effort finally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242376/linear-gradient-with-round-corners?noredirect=1#comment100993477_57242376) ;-)

Comment: OP required: each rectangular bar with round corners (without any changes in html)

Comment: Is there a way to change the calculations to allow width set to 100%? If I set it at 100%, the right hand side is square, not round.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try this approach instead of making one div output multiple gradient boxes?

```css
.myStyle {
  width:150px;
  height:100px;
  background:linear-gradient(black,purple);
  border-radius:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myStyle"></div>
```

Comment: This works only if one linear-gradient is present. It dosent work for multiple linear-gradients. Please help me in providing solution for one div itself.